# Alternatives to bibtex2html

Tags: bibtex, conversion, html

As the title says, are there viable alternatives to [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) for converting bibliographic entries to HTML?

I am specifically looking for some command-line utility allowing to export a `bib` files to HTML, XML or text-based files, although dedicated GUI would do the job as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some others to consider:

[bib2ml (CTAN)](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bib2ml/)

[bib2xhtml](http://www.spinellis.gr/sw/textproc/bib2xhtml/)

[bibhtml](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/bibhtml/)

the bib2xml component of [bibutils](http://www.scripps.edu/~cdputnam/software/bibutils/)

I'm afraid I don't really have any experience with these, so I can't recommend one over another.

Comment: (+1) Looks fine, thx! I came across those pages some time ago, but forgot about them since then. I tried `bib2xhtml` (easy install, lot of default styles) and it works out of the box. The `bibutils` suite could be useful too as it directly output XML files (not tried yet).

Answer (score 11):

[BibBase](http://bibbase.org) is another solution. Unlike the other tools it's a web service whose output you can embed into your page. So there is nothing to install.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of bibbase.org. But hey, this one was asking for this specifically.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thanks for the pointer, looks like a helpful resource. In case you’re the creator of BibBase, please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion.

Answer (score 6):

[JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) can export to `html`. There are different `html` converters available. It is also possible to call JabRef from the [command line](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CommandLine.php) without starting the GUI.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for this. I didn't know JabRef could be used in CLI mode. Note: I've also upvoted @Martin response as you answered quite at the same time (+/- 1 min).

Comment: @chl: If you think that suggestion is a good answer to your question, you might consider to accept it by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. Of course you can accept the answer which helped you most.

Comment: Yes, I know how SE works. I am generally waiting at least two days (esp. during weekend) before accepting an answer.

Comment: @chl Sorry, I did not want to be rude or pushy.

Comment: No prob. I accepted @frabjous's answer because I was mainly looking for a CLI solution, but yours was very welcome too.

Answer (score 2):

[JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) (GUI) can do it. See also these [export filters](http://www.markschenk.com/tools/jabref/).

Comment: (+1) thanks a lot, see also my comment to @domwass.