# How to generate a bibliography website from BiBTeX

Tags: bibtex

I have BiBTeX files and want to generate a bibliography website (for my research group) from the BiBTeX. Are there good tools for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate (although a bit old): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/alternatives-to-bibtex2html

Comment: take a look at nelson beebe's web site, especially [BibTeX Information and Tutorial](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/bibnet/bibtex-info.html).  nelson has compiled more bibtex bibliographies than anyone else i know of.  he has also contributed several articles on the subject to tugboat.  (if this answers your question, i'll write a more elaborate answer, with more links.)

Comment: Marijn, yes, that is helpful. barbara beeton, no, this is not about generating websites.

Comment: More precisely: barbara beeton, no, yours is not about generating websites, and I want to generate a website.

Comment: What about a community wiki to collect the various alternatives.

Comment: If your question is about creating a website, it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Mico, I disagree. This question is about "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.", namely about a tool for rendering BibTeX input in a specific way. Guido, yes, I think it is useful to collect the answers, because many people will have a similar question (e.g. researchers at a university typically need to publish their bibliography online).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the author of [BibSpace](http://hex64.com/) ([Github](https://github.com/vikin91/BibSpace)). The system is designed to manage publications and display them on a webpage. The code works perfect for our group (see [example](http://se.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/publications/publications_browser/)) but I am the only developer so far and there is a lot of room to make it better. You are free to fork the code and use it for your group. I am happy to help if you have questions.

Edit: Please note that I am now working on cleaning up the BibSpace code and making the installation easier by providing install scripts. I will update this answer and provide links to up-to-date installation procedure.

Edit2: I described BibSpace in my [blog](https://blog.hex64.com/bibspace-online-bibtex-publications-management-software-for-authors-and-research-groups/). The Github repository contains now stable version 0.4.

Comment: This looks interesting! Is it also possible to select publications by author?

Comment: Yes, you have a lot of filtering possibilities. You can filter by author, team, tags, type, category, years and most of them combined together. For example, all my papers tagged as "performance" from year 2014: http://se2.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/pa/ly/p?tag=Performance&author=RygielskiPiotr&year=2014&title=1&switchlink=1&navbar=1
And here all tags of my papers: http://se2.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/pa/read/tags-for-author/RygielskiPiotr

You embed these snippets on your webpage and the content is directly generated by the system. We use it in our group at the university.